# convert columns in rows

Tags: oracle, cursor, limit, chunks

My general problem is that I have 10000 distinct numbers as a list of (i.e. 13, 22, 443, ..., 5010 - not in a table AND CANNOT create a table of them) and i need to loop through these numbers in chunks (1..100, 101..200, 202..300, etc. - 1st 100 number, next 100 number and so on ...)

My 1st reaction was to create a cursor and loop in it with the LIMIT clause but I am not sure if it is possible.

Is there any way to define a cursor with these specific values? If not can someone suggest me some other possibility, please?

Maybe a select all values from dual and transform them from columns into rows and from here create a cursor, is it possible?

Thank you,

Comment: Is it all numbers between 1 and 10000 or just a random(ish) list of numbers of which there happen to be 10000 ?

Comment: the numbers are random(ish), for example, the 678th number can be 1940049 but count(all_numbers) = 10000.

Comment: So presumably you have the numbers in a list somewhere ? Maybe another database or a file . . . If so then you can either link to the other database or create an external table definition for the number list file and use that in a cursor loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

```
cursor c is
    with test as
        (select 709941, 709959, 710165, 710183, 710199, 710201, 710203, 710220, 710352, 710571, 710630, 710710, 710714, 710723, 710724, 710761, 710845, 710877, 710878, 710892, 710908, 710915' col from dual)
            select regexp_substr(col, '[^;]+', 1, level) result
            from test
            connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(col, '[^;]+')) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a [PL/SQL collection](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-collections-and-records.htm#LNPLS005) with those specific values:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE t_table IS TABLE OF PLS_INTEGER;
  v_list t_table;
BEGIN
  v_list := t_table(13, 22, 443, 5010);
  FOR n IN v_list.FIRST .. v_list.LAST LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_list(n));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

13
22
443
5010
```

That will create a collection of `PLS_INTEGERS` (can also be `NUMBER` or any other data type) and loop through all the elements in that collection.